# Как перефразировать предложение?

Tags: лексическая

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно перефразировать предложение, в котором смешение разговорного и художественного стилей речи.

Для Есенина никакая пальма не могла идти в сравнение даже с самой маленькой вшивой (можно некрасивой?) берёзкой.

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для Есенина никакая пальма не сравнилась бы даже с самой убогой берёзкой.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. )